# How to get list of keys from a JSON object in Ansible?

Tags: json, ansible

I have a JSON like this:

```
"ip":{
  "192.17.130.01":{
    string:"pararam"
 }
  "192.17.130.02":{
    string:"tararam"
 }
}
```

How can I get a list of IPs using Ansible?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution for you:

```
- set_fact:
    my_list_of_ips: "{{ ip | from_json | list }}"
```

Using a [`list` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list) on a dictionary will produce a list of its keys.

Apply [`from_json` filter](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) if the input is a JSON string (otherwise you can skip it).

<sup>Remember dictionaries are not sorted, so don't be surprised the order on the resulting list is different to what you see on the screen above.</sup>

Comment: Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)